# Heroku: ! You do not have access to the app heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I originally had an app with the default name heroku set up. However I wanted to change this so I had two apps, an staging and production app. Following the heroku guide [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) I think i've got it working, running `git remote -v` shows

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:oldapp.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:oldapp.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:newapp.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:newapp.git (push)
```

but I now want to change the name of heroku to "production". Running `heroku apps:rename production --app heroku` results in:

```
Renaming heroku to production... failed
 !    You do not have access to the app heroku.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you want to rename the app - I think you want to rename the name of the remote origin? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: sometimes is a different name, checkout your Heroku page admin and see the real name app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rename a git origin perform the following;

```
git remote rename heroku production
```

this will now let you do

```
git push production master
```

to deploy your application.

Comment: ah that's done the trick thanks, it was the origin I wanted to rename(without realising it) Think I need to read up a bit more on git

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "*production*" app in your heroku account.
(You have to have the new app name in your account.)

So basically your command should be something like :

```
heroku apps:rename newapp --app oldapp
```

You **cannot** rename **heroku** since its not your app.