# Why does an error occur when remoting Heroku Git?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to host a discord bot on heroku and for that I need to install some things using the command prompt. I almost succeeded, but when I entered the "heroku git:remote -a forexbotserver" according to the instructions, an error appeared.how can I fix this? I'm new to heroku and git, please help me :(

```
Error: You do not have access to the app forexbotserver.

Error ID: forbidden
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742946/heroku-you-do-not-have-access-to-the-app-heroku

Comment: What commands did you run in the command prompt?